# Blender 2.81 bad shadows (missing settings)

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Seems like new version has no shadow settings. I read that new version should calculate and make setting automatically for better results. But it look much worse. Any ideas? 
2.80[image: 2.80] 
2.81[image: 2.81] 
Settings:

2.80[image: 2.80 settings]
2.81[image: 2.81 settings]

Comment: It's hard to tell without know what settings you are using. Perhaps add a screenshot of your lamp and global eevee shadow settings

Comment: Of course. Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.81 has better shadow algorithm, the final result will deliver a higher quality shadow, but it needs more samples in order to get to that result.

Go to the Properties `Render` tab and in the `Sampling` panel increase the number of samples.

Comment: This doesn't help, before I used to adjust Exponent to get the contact shadows to the exact look I wanted (there had been light leaks), now the parameter is missing and the light leaks are back

Answer (score 0):

In the *Render properties* panel there is a section for *Shadows*:

[image: Shadows Panel]

These affect the Eevee render engine globally.

- *Cube Size* affects point and area light shadow maps
- *Cascade Size* affects sun light shadow maps

The rest of the controls are quite self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I know it feels like it is kinda obvious, but I say it: have you tried restarting it?
I'had been looking for an answer for that question, and nothing helped. I was fed up, closed it, but it bothered me so much, that in a half an hour I've started it again, and voila, the problem was gone.

Comment: If it doesn't work on the first attempted restart how many more  to be sure?  Apologies for the terrible attempt at sarcasm. ... but...  _Have you tried restarting?_ could  be the answer to everything, rarely solves anything.

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording. I state it again: after several attempts, I did just that, and the problem was gone. Maybe my pc was doing it weird, maybe... I have zero ideas about why it worked. When I modified something, I always resetted the value to the original, to avoid an effect caused by several factors, but none of it solved the issue. In this case, what should I say? It helped with none of the issues before, but it did in this case. If you say I should, I will just delete my answer. Now I see, your way works much better /sorry for the terrible attempt on sarcasm/

Comment: NP with you leaving it.  Added comment as it came up in late answers review...  will see if it makes thru the others (review is 2020 version of Spanish inquisition)  wouldn't be able to count how often someone comes to me with a computer problem and gets same advice.. when they ask what the problem was.. "_No Idea_ ".  Welcome to BSE 8^)